# Wpf datagrid Enter key move next row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to develop a wpf app with a datagrid, and i want to allow the users to enter values like in excel.

Example:
The datagrid has 2 columns, Name and BarCode
The user is editing the BarCode on the first row, and when the user press Enter key, the focus should move the the row below on the BarCode cell.

The user must be able to use a barcode scanner to register the barcodes, on the existing products list, without need to user the mouse or the keyboard.

Any ideas on how to implement this behavior?

Thanks,
Frederico

Comment: You want the datagrid to handle the Enter Key like the Tab Key?

Comment: No, The tab key sets the focus to the next cell, i need the focus to be set on the same column, but in the row below of the current.
Like in excel, when the user is editing a cell, when he press enter the cell below receives focus and start edit.

Comment: But it's already like excel..
can u explain more?

Comment: my problem is to move and edit the the cell below, after hit enter

Answer (score 8):

A simpler solution is capture the KeyDown event and if the key is 'Enter', then move to the next tab.

```
private void dg_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var u = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && u != null)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        u.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just done this with some extra code, by handle the PreviewKeyUp event on the Datagrid, the working code is:

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Key == Key.Enter) || (e.Key == Key.Return))
    {
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        if (grid.CurrentColumn.Header.ToString().Equals("Barcode", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (grid.SelectionUnit == DataGridSelectionUnit.Cell || grid.SelectionUnit == DataGridSelectionUnit.CellOrRowHeader)
            {
                var focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
                focusedElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down));
             }

             grid.BeginEdit();
             e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The Column that hold the Barcode property is the only one i need for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

//MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace BarcodeImplementationInDG
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<Products> lst = new List<Products>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dg.ItemsSource = lst;
        }
    }
    public class Products
    {
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

//MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="BarcodeImplementationInDG.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="309" Width="507" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ProductColumn" Binding="{Binding Product}" Header="Product"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="BarcodeColumn" Binding="{Binding Barcode}" Header="Barcode"  />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Data will be stored in the List *lst*, in case you want to use them

On Enter, The focus automatically moves to the second row..

Comment: Yes the focus is set automatic, but i need to start edit the cell, without more user interation.
The user is editing barcode cell, when he press enter, the focus is set to the cell below, and he can start typing a new value, without double click the new cell

Comment: it doesn't need any user interactions, just start scanning or typing.

Comment: the edit start on the first cell, right?
i need to edit the cell on the row below, of the same column.
Like editing on excel

Comment: maybe a full scenario would help me figure out your problem, or start a chat on stackoverflow here

Comment: Thanks for your help,

A full scenario:
I have a products list, and it's displayed on a datagrid, with Name, Code, Barcode and Quantity columns.
I need to update the stocks on the products, the Quantity column.
To allow the user to do this task more quickly, when editing the Quantity on the first product, he press enter key, and he needs to start to input the Quantity on the second product.

So the user do, Quantity, Enter, Quantity, Enter, .... and so until is done.
My problem is to move the focus, and start editint, only be pressing the enter key

Answer (score 0):

If 3rd party WPF Grids are acceptable, [Essential Grid](http://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sfdatagrid/overview) can be used as it has this Excel like behavior built into the Grid.

The whole suite of controls is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. Note: I work for Syncfusion.