# WPF Datagrid How to enter edit mode of cell when moving to the next row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm attempting to have a datagrid where once a cell has been edited and on Enter press the cursor moves to the same column in the next row down and immediately enters edit mode.

I need the exact behaviour as in this question: [Wpf datagrid Enter key move next row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292455/wpf-datagrid-enter-key-move-next-row)

however the solution given there isn't working, I have to press the enter key again to enter edit mode. The cell to be edited is in the column named "MeasuredResult"

xaml:

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Aliquot ID" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding AliquotId}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="MeasuredResult" Header="MeasuredResult" Width="Auto" >                       
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding MeasuredResult, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnlyMeasuredResult}" 
                                     BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Unit" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Unit}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("key down handler entered, key pressed = " + e.Key);

            if ((e.Key == Key.Enter) || (e.Key == Key.Return))
            {
                DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
                
                var focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
                focusedElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down));
                grid.SelectedItem = grid.CurrentItem;
                
                grid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(grid.CurrentItem, grid.Columns[4]);
                
                grid.BeginEdit();                
                e.Handled = true;                
            }
        }
```

I have tried setting the focus on the specific cell first using:

```
grid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(grid.CurrentItem, grid.Columns[4]);
DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)grid.CurrentCell.Column.GetCellContent(grid.CurrentCell.Item).Parent;
cell.Focus();
```

which stops editmode from being entered entirely.
And I have tried changing the SelectedUnit in the datagrid to Cell and the same basic behaviour still happens.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that if I change the column from a `DataGridTemplateColumn`
to a `DataGridTextColumn`, i.e:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="MeasuredResult" Binding="{Binding MeasuredResult, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="MeasuredResult" />
```

Then I get the behaviour I want.